# JSON parameter in multipart form PUT request in iOS Swift using AlmoFire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to upload image using Multipart/formdata put request in iOS Swift using Almofire Networking which has few parameters and one parameter contains JSON. e.g

```
"parameter_name":{
"field_1" : {
  "type" : "MULTISELECT",
  "value" : [
    "Option 1",
    "Option 3"
  ],
  "name" : "Multi Selection"
},
"field_2" : {
  "type" : "DATE",
  "name" : "BirthDate",
  "value" : "2000-09-08"
},
"field_3" : {
  "type" : "SINGLESELECT",
  "value" : "Option1",
  "name" : "Single Select"
}
}
```

This is one parameter in multipart formdata with other parameters like name, email, photo and more (all are of type string)
Could anyone help me achieving this as using Swift & AlamoFire As I am receiving 503 status code for this.
Note:- In postman same API is working fine.

What I have done so far is:

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartData in
        parameters.forEach { (key, value) in
            if let arrdata = (value as? [AnyHashable : Any]) {
                if arrdata.count > 0 {
                    let arrdatas =  try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrdata, options: [])
                    multipartData.append(arrdatas, withName: key as String)
                }  
            }
            guard
                let data = (value as? String)?
                    .data(using: .utf8)
                else { return }
            multipartData.append(data, withName: key)
        }
        if let img = photo,
            let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.0) {
            multipartData
                .append(data,
                        withName: Keys.photo,
                        fileName: Keys.fileName,
                        mimeType: Keys.mimeType)
        }
    },
                     to: "My URL",

                     headers: requestType.headers,
                     encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                        switch encodingResult {
                        case .success(let upload, _, _):
                            upload.responseData(completionHandler: { response in
                                if let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode,
                                    200 <= statusCode && statusCode < 300,
                                    let data = response.data {
                                    guard
                                        let decoded = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []),
                                        let dic = decoded as? [String: Any] else {
                                            return
                                    }
                                    printOnlyOnDebug("Response got is --> \(self.convertToJSON(toConvert: dic))")
                                    
                                    success(data)
                                } else {
                                    guard
                                        let data = response.data,
                                        let decoded = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []),
                                        let dic = decoded as? [String: Any],
                                        let message = dic[Keys.message] as? String else {
                                            let code = response.response?.statusCode == 503 ? 401 : response.response?.statusCode
                                            failure(code, "Network error")
                                            return
                                    }
                                    failure(response.response?.statusCode, message)
                                }
                            })
                        case .failure(let error):
                            failure(nil, error.localizedDescription)
                        }
    })
```

Also header contains `'Content-Type' as 'multipart/form-data'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to mention method type PUT in AlamoFire request so it was creating POST request and it was causing the issue.

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartData in
    parameters.forEach { (key, value) in
        if let arrdata = (value as? [AnyHashable : Any]) {
            if arrdata.count > 0 {
                let arrdatas =  try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrdata, options: [])
                multipartData.append(arrdatas, withName: key as String)
            }  
        }
        guard
            let data = (value as? String)?
                .data(using: .utf8)
            else { return }
        multipartData.append(data, withName: key)
    }
    if let img = photo,
        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.0) {
        multipartData
            .append(data,
                    withName: Keys.photo,
                    fileName: Keys.fileName,
                    mimeType: Keys.mimeType)
    }
},
                 to: "My URL",
                 method:.put,
                 headers: requestType.headers,
                 encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                    switch encodingResult {
                    case .success(let upload, _, _):
                        upload.responseData(completionHandler: { response in
                            if let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode,
                                200 <= statusCode && statusCode < 300,
                                let data = response.data {
                                guard
                                    let decoded = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []),
                                    let dic = decoded as? [String: Any] else {
                                        return
                                }
                                printOnlyOnDebug("Response got is --> \(self.convertToJSON(toConvert: dic))")
                                
                                success(data)
                            } else {
                                guard
                                    let data = response.data,
                                    let decoded = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []),
                                    let dic = decoded as? [String: Any],
                                    let message = dic[Keys.message] as? String else {
                                        let code = response.response?.statusCode == 503 ? 401 : response.response?.statusCode
                                        failure(code, "Network error")
                                        return
                                }
                                failure(response.response?.statusCode, message)
                            }
                        })
                    case .failure(let error):
                        failure(nil, error.localizedDescription)
                    }
})
```